# How can I access the location of Shalidor's writings in Wolfskull Cave?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've researched bugs on this quest and have not resolved the inability to access the location of Shalidor's writings when directed to Wolfskull Cave.  I had completed the "The Man Who Cried Wolf" quest before I began the Shalidor's Writings quest, although I do not recall which of the two quests I received first.

Does the order I received the quests matter?  More importantly, is there a way to fix this quest so I can retrieve the writings and complete the quest?

If it helps, I'm playing the PC version.

Comment: You haven't told us what your problem is.

Comment: I am not able to access the location of Shalidor's writings in Wolfskull Cave.  The pointer points to a location on the floor that sits outside of the map - there is no pathway to the location.  everything I've researched says it has to do with not completing the Man Who Cried Wolf quest, but I completed that quest long before I even began the Shalidor's Writing/Insights quest given by the librarian from the Arcaneum. My problem is I want to know if Shalidor's Writings quest can be fixed and completed, or if I'm just going to have to let it sit there incomplete the rest of the game?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PC, try this command `setstage MGR21 20`, the game should act like you have collected the item. If you're not on PC, there isn't anything you can do, but at least this quest isn't very important.

Comment: Thank you very much Kotekzot.  Now for the million dollar stupid question.  Where and how do I enter that command - and yes, I'm playing on the PC :)?

Comment: Hit the grave/tilde key (`/~), it should be under Escape and left of 1.